# reading an excel spreadsheet into java

Tags: java, input, spreadsheet

I am attempting to automate a lengthy and redundant process with my amateur Java programming skills. The process is to take names and dates from one spreadsheet and update individual spreadsheets with the new information (each name on the main sheet has his or her own separate sheet that updates and saves with a new date in the title.

I've download JExcelApi to assist with reading and writing to excel, but I still cannot grasp how to initially scan or read in a spreadsheet. If anyone can point me in a direction here or provide some assistance that would be appreciated.

I don't have much so far since I'm stuck in the initial process, actually reading in the spreadsheet, or else I'd provide code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), download the [poi.x.yy-date.jar](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) in tar.gz or zip format. The [How-To page](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api) has an example.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;


public class ReadExcel { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\spreadsheet.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            HSSFSheet    ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
            HSSFRow      r1 = ws.getRow(0);
            HSSFCell     A1 = r1.getCell((short) 0);
            HSSFCell     A2 = r1.getCell((short) 1);
            HSSFCell     A3 = r1.getCell((short) 2);
            System.out.println("A1: " + A1.getStringCellValue() + " A2: " + A2.getStringCellValue() + " A3: " + A3.getStringCellValue() );
            HSSFRow      r2 = ws.getRow(1);
            HSSFCell     B1 = r2.getCell((short) 0);
            HSSFCell     B2 = r2.getCell((short) 1);
            HSSFCell     B3 = r2.getCell((short) 2);
            System.out.println("B1: " + B1.getNumericCellValue() + " B2: " + B2.getNumericCellValue() + " B3: " + B3.getNumericCellValue() );

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```